# Recursif list of subclasses

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering why this code didn't work:

```
class Module
  def self.classes(base_module)
    arr = []

    base_module.constants(false).each do |constant|
      object = base_module.const_get(constant, false)

      if object.is_a?(Class)
        arr << object
      else
        arr.concat object.controllers(object)
      end
    end

    arr
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar
  end

  module Ok
    module OkOk
      class Ooooook
      end
    end
  end
end

Foo.classes Foo
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `classes' for Foo:Module

BTW, is there a more simple way to fetch all sub-classes from a given module? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work because you defined `classes` as a `Module` object's singleton class method. It should be without `self.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Foo` is an instance of `Module`. Thus you need to define `classes` as an instance method.

```
class Module
  def classes(base_module)
    arr = []

    base_module.constants(false).each do |constant|
      object = base_module.const_get(constant, false)

      if object.is_a?(Class)
        arr << object
      else
        arr.concat object.classes(object)
      end
    end

    arr
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar
  end

  module Ok
    module OkOk
      class Ooooook
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Foo.classes Foo
# >> Foo::Bar
# >> Foo::Ok::OkOk::Ooooook
```